# Stormpath cURL Error

Tags: stormpath

I am trying to follow this example: http://docs.stormpath.com/rest/quickstart/
One of the steps mentions to do the following cURL request:

```
curl -X POST --user $YOUR_API_KEY_ID:$YOUR_API_KEY_SECRET \
 -H "Accept: application/json" \
 -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
 -d '{
       "name" : "My Awesome Application"
     }' \
 'https://api.stormpath.com/v1/applications?createDirectory=true'
```

I am using online cURL from : http://onlinecurl.com/
Here is the snapshot of the curl request:
[image: Curl Request Snapshot]
Here is the snapshot of the Header Response:
[image: Curl Response Snapshot]

Can anybody please tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm also having problems with that tool.  I tried what you show in your screenshot, plus some other combinations.  I actually get a different error (media type unauthorized).  I suspect this tool uses some kind of proxy that is messing with the request.

Comment: I used Git Bash curl command and it worked fine. The online-curl tool really messes things up.